# How to convert Mongo DB query to Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a Mongo DB query which needs to convert using MongoEngine. consider below query and I wanted to implement the same in MongoEngine ORM. I'm very much new to MongoDB and MongoEngine. thanks in advance

```
    db.my_collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$quizzes"
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$quizzes.skill",
            "k":{
                $first:"$quizzes.skill"
            },
            "v":{
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "data":{
                $push:"$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "data":{
                $arrayToObject:"$data"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            "newRoot":"$data"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

the above mongo query will give following result

{
 "skill1": 40,
 "skill2": 50,
 "skill3": 23,
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
}

I wanted to have the same result. but the implementation should be from MongoEngine ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your model and pipeline, you can use `YourModel.objects.aggregate()` ([doc](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=aggregate#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.aggregate)) to run it.

E.g:

```
class Person(Document):
    name = StringField()

agg_pipeline = [{"$project": {"name": {"$toUpper": "$name"}}}]
agg_result = list(Person.objects.aggregate(*agg_pipeline))

print(agg_result)    # prints [{'_id': ObjectId('5d69225b44fec38d49c050f2'), 'name': 'JOHN'}]
```

EDIT:

There is no better (or more ORM-ish) support for aggregation in mongoengine due to its complex nature, it is a simple gateway to pymongo. (mongoengine maintainer here)

Comment: thanks for your response. I've updated the question with the response I need. Kindly have a look at the description and update.